# Is there a Jewish database on Tanach syntax?

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk, text

Westminster is a downloadable version of the Leningrad Codex [version of Tanach], http://tanach.us/Tanach.xml. One thing they have there is a database that includes syntax for all of Tanach. It was a Christian project, and obviously there are choices in it that will be debatable.
Is there is any equivalent in the Torah world (or even the secular academic Jewish world): an available database for syntax of Tanach?

Comment: What do you mean by "syntax"?

Comment: Marking each word, or parts of words, as Noun, Verb, Preposition, Direct Object... Unfortunately I am not familiar with all the modern terms. [בְּ, רֵאשִׁ֖ית, בָּרָ֣א, אֱלֹהִ֑ים, אֵ֥ת, הַ, שָּׁמַ֖יִם, וְ, אֵ֥ת, הָ, אָֽרֶץ] [sentence_atom, VC, PP, prep, subs, VP, verb, NP, subs, PP, prep, art, subs, conj, prep, art, subs]. I think. That second list is a tree structure in Polish notation, with larger structures followed by what they contain, if I parsed it right.

Comment: A concordance? 15 char.

Comment: But also showing the sentence structure.

Comment: I know of an artscroll tanach where at the end of the book it has the book again but with shorashim highlighted or something like that

Comment: The Artstcroll Chinuch Tiferes Micha'el https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422615249.html has that in the back. It tells you the shoresh, and each word is numbered with a number 1-7 representing one of the seven Binyanim.

Comment: Thank you, but I need a machine-readable database.